# Storing basic arithmetic operators in variables

Tags: c++, operators, switch-statement, arithmetic-expressions

**How can I store a basic arithmetic operator in a variable?**

I'd like to do something like this in c++:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
operator op = +;
int c = a op b;
if (c == 3) // do something
```

Since I'm considering only `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` I could store the operator in a `string` and just use a switch statement. However I'm wondering if there's a better/easier way.

Comment: Look into how the STL functions take predicates. You can use things such as `std::plus`.

Comment: Is `enum` an option? What specifically is wrong with the strings/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
std::function<int(int, int)> op = std::plus<int>();
int c = op(a, b);
if (c == 3) // do something
```

Replace `std::plus<>` with `std::minus<>`, `std::multiplies<>`, `std::divides<>`, etc., as need be. All of these are located in the header `functional`, so be sure to `#include <functional>` beforehand.

Replace `std::function<>` with [`boost::function<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/function/) if you're not using a recent compiler.